# Angular.js - Using a filter to alter a variable

Tags: angularjs

This sounds simple, but googling is coming up trumps. I have a dropdown select that has multiple categories:

```
<select ng-model="orderProp" >
  <option ng-repeat="cats in categories" value="{{cats}}">{{cats}}</option>
</select>
```

I also have a map, using [Angular Google Maps](http://nlaplante.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api), which uses JSON data to plot markers. The data for these markers is called `$scope.markersProperty`

When a users uses the select box, I'd like to dynamically change the value of markersProperty. Using Angular's HTML `{{}}` I can get the results I want with a simple:

`{{markersProperty|filter:orderProp}}`

But I can't for the life of me work out how to get similar functionality to update the array `$scope.markersProperty`. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use markersProperty as ng-model on select box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to update the scope variable, then you can use the `$filter` service:

```js
.controller('MainCtrl', function ( $scope, $filter ) {
  $scope.markersProperty = // ...

  $scope.$watch( 'orderProp', function ( val ) {
    $scope.filteredMarkersProperty = $filter('filter')($scope.markersProperty, val);
  });
});
```